# How to translate this SQL into mongodb? -- adding 2 strings

Tags: mongodb

How to translate this SQL:

```
Select fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName from People
```

into MongoDB's query?

```
db.People.find(???) 

db.People.aggregate(???)
```

here is the people collection

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56215bef66a6d31bdccc717e"),
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName" : "White"
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56215c1e66a6d31bdccc717f"),
  "firstName" : "Paul",
  "lastName" : "Smith"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [$concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operator. Below is an example which might give you some idea.

```
db.People.aggregate(
   [
      { $project: { fullName: { $concat: [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Firing up the aggregation pipeline for a simple string concatenation feels a bit like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer to me. Especially since displaying is a frontend thingy.